# LaTeX Giving many begin document and misplaced alignment tab character errors

Tags: latex

I'm working on creating some top trump cards for a small project in LaTeX. Since I didn't know where to start I found a similar project and will work on editing it.

I found this Git repository which is basically exactly what I'm looking for

https://github.com/benstox/TopTrumps/blob/master/cards.tex

I shortened it down to just try and do one card for now rather than thirty cards, and will work up to thirty.

This is the copied and pasted code with the other 29 cards removed.

```
documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}

%   Merge packages
\input{include/libs.tex}
%   Load colour definitions
\input{include/colors.tex}
%   Load card commands
\input{include/tikzcards.tex}

%   Dummy-Contents
\newcommand{\contentA}{Neunmalkluges Zitat\\mit Bezug zur Karte von einer fiktiven Figur.}
\newcommand{\contentB}{Fun: 80\\Holy: 100}
\newcommand{\contentC}{Oh hi.}
\newcommand{\scores}[8]{
\begin{tabular}{l r}
Cake (volume):&#1 table(s)\\Cake (taste):&#2\ding{72}\\Rest time:&#3\\Originality:&#4/10\\Hospitality:&#5\%\\Timeliness:&#6/10\\Luxury:&#7\ding{72}\\Prayerfulness:&#8/10\\
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \pagestyle{empty}

%   V-Space-Korrektur bei langen Titeln
%   \cardtitle{\vspace{-5mm}SEHR LANGER TITEL}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \cardbackground{img/Epping1.jpg}
        \cardtypeEssex
        \cardtitle{Epping}
        \cardcontent{Morning of Feast of St Joseph; we set off.}{\scores{0}{0}{12h}{7}{83}{10}{2}{7}}
        \cardprice{2}
        \cardborder
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have the .tex documents downloaded and in a folder called include within overleaf.

I am still geting a lot of errors.

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. (8)

LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. (21)

Missing $ inserted. (22)

Misplaced alignment tab character &. (28)

After this its basically missing begin documents and misplaced alignment tab on nearly every line.

I don't use LaTeX too often and was wondering how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Other than the missing \ before documentclass, your code works fine for me. Did you double check that you are compiling the correct file and not some included file?

Comment: Sorry I do have that \ in mine it just didnt copy. Weird, I checked in settings and it says the main document is set to 'cards.tex' - the name of the file i'm using for the main. Edit: just to double check I deleted the whole project, remade a new one using this code and it's coming up with the exact same errors.

Comment: Can you link to your overleaf project?

Comment: Sure thing! https://www.overleaf.com/5561595185sgqbnnxfzmzc

Comment: The files in your include folder are corrupted. Try to upload them again

Comment: now the only error should be the missing image

Comment: Your image is in the same folder as your main file. Thus the path `img/Avocet.jpg` is wrong, there is no folder called `img`

Comment: What was the problem and how did you solve it?

Comment: I believe re-uploading the .tex files fixed this problem.